# HKQuantityTypeIdentifier initialize with string

Tags: ios, swift, healthkit

I am trying to create HKObjectType like following however all values are nill. I get enum values by string so I need to create object to get authentication.

```
let c = HKObjectType.quantityType(forIdentifier: HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.init(rawValue: "bodyFatPercentage"))

let d = HKObjectType.quantityType(forIdentifier: HKQuantityTypeIdentifier(rawValue: "BodyFatPercentage"))

let e = HKObjectType.quantityType(forIdentifier: HKQuantityTypeIdentifier(rawValue: "bodyFatPercentage"))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The raw value is wrong, check this

```
print(HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.bodyFatPercentage.rawValue)
// HKQuantityTypeIdentifierBodyFatPercentage
```

so you got to write

```
let e = HKObjectType.quantityType(forIdentifier: HKQuantityTypeIdentifier(rawValue: "HKQuantityTypeIdentifierBodyFatPercentage"))
```

But why not

```
let c = HKObjectType.quantityType(forIdentifier: .bodyFatPercentage)
```